# How does one draw a box around some sibling HTML elements?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to visually highlight a set of sibling elements that share the same attribute.

```css
#boxed_contents span[data-boxme] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxed_contents">
    <span>hello</span><!--
 --><span>world</span><!--
 --><span data-boxme>look</span><!--
 --><span data-boxme>at</span><!--
 --><span data-boxme>me</span>
</div>
```

This *almost* works like I want it to, but I'd like to join the boxes around each of the `boxme` elements, leaving just one box around all three elements. I know I can wrap the adjacent `boxme` elements in a wrapper div, but since this is conceptually a visual (rather than a structural) choice, I'd really like to do this without modifying the HTML.

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS? Failing that, with the addition of some straightforward Javascript?

Comment: Why can't your elements be put in one `span` by the code behind?

Comment: @bytecode77 They each need to be in a separate span because I need to handle click events on each of the spans.

Comment: This is not necessarily a pure design decision. CSS works around the logical HTML structure of your page. While it is possible to have a pure CSS answer to this particular question (@Hashem Qolami), I think a wrapper div around the content would help to explain that the content is logically grouped.

Comment: @smcjones I'd agree, but given that the `boxme` elements can change dynamically, it becomes more cumbersome to have JavaScript manipulating the creation, destruction, and modification of these wrapper divs just for a cleaner visual look. That's not a deal-breaker, but I was hoping to discover a simpler way of handling this.

Comment: It's probably going to be quicker than having JavaScript filter through the DOM to find a custom attribute to apply CSS to. I think the burden of a wrapper is outweighed by its merits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hashem for putting me on the right track with the sibling selector (to uniquely style consecutive elements), and a pseudo-selector to add border elements.

I have had to add a line of JavaScript to ensure that there is a blank `span` element without the `boxme` attribute at the very end. By doing so, I can use the `:before` pseudo element on any non-`boxme` element following a `boxme` element. The main advantage to this strategy (over the one given by Hashem) is that I get to keep the rounded corners from my original CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('boxed_contents').appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
```

```css
#boxed_contents span[data-boxme] {
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
#boxed_contents span[data-boxme] + span[data-boxme] {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#boxed_contents span[data-boxme] + span:not([data-boxme]):before {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxed_contents">
    <span>hello</span><!--
 --><span>world</span><!--
 --><span data-boxme>look</span><!--
 --><span data-boxme>at</span><!--
 --><span data-boxme>me</span>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how cross-platform this solution is, but it seems to work well on my target platform of Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

Actually it is not possible to wrap elements in a another one by pure CSS. But we can somehow fake the effect by adding border to each adjacent element and putting an absolutely positioned pseudo-element over the middle borders.

As an aside, note that custom attributes are not valid in HTML unless they are formatted as [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

```css
#boxed_contents [data-boxme] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
}

#boxed_contents [data-boxme] + [data-boxme] {
  margin-left: -.25em;
  padding-left: .25em;
  position: relative;
}

#boxed_contents [data-boxme] + [data-boxme]:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: -4px;
  width: 4px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxed_contents">
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>world</span>
  <span data-boxme>look</span>
  <span data-boxme>at</span>
  <span data-boxme>me</span>
  <span>not me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks funny if I want to stick with the rounded `border-radius` corners, but it's so far the only answer that even addresses the question as asked. I'm giving this +1 because it looks good as long as I avoid using a `border-radius`. I would accept this answer if it worked well with `border-radius`.

Comment: @user108471 I'm afraid that it is not possible to achieve that as there's no feature in CSS to match only the *last* adjecent sibling element without touching the middle siblings. `A + A` adjacent selector matches `A`s starting from the 2nd `A`.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track to finding a solution (which I've posted as a new answer) that keeps the rounded corners on my original question. Using the sibling selector and `:before`, I was able to accomplish my goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/mnpyqgsf/) work for you?

```
var borderProps='2px solid #f00',borderRadius='5px',boxMeAttr='data-boxme';
var spans=document.querySelectorAll('span'),boxMeArrays=[],dummyArray=null,iterator=0;
var currSpan=null,prevSpan=null;
var i,length=spans.length,adjacentSpans=0;
for(i=0; i<length; i+=1){
    prevSpan=currSpan;
    currSpan=spans[i];
    if(currSpan.hasAttribute(boxMeAttr)){
        if(prevSpan!==null&&prevSpan.hasAttribute(boxMeAttr)){
            dummyArray[dummyArray.length]=currSpan;
        }else{
            dummyArray=[currSpan];
            boxMeArrays[iterator]=dummyArray;
            iterator+=1;
        }
    }
}
length=boxMeArrays.length;
for(i=0; i<length; i+=1){
    adjacentSpans=boxMeArrays[i].length;
    for(var j=0; j<adjacentSpans; j+=1){
        currSpan=boxMeArrays[i][j];
        if(adjacentSpans>1){
            if(j===0){
                currSpan.innerText+=' ';
                currSpan.style.borderLeft=currSpan.style.borderTop=currSpan.style.borderBottom=borderProps;
                currSpan.style.borderTopLeftRadius=currSpan.style.borderBottomLeftRadius=borderRadius;
            }else if(j===adjacentSpans-1){
                currSpan.style.borderTop=currSpan.style.borderBottom=currSpan.style.borderRight=borderProps;
                currSpan.style.borderTopRightRadius=currSpan.style.borderBottomRightRadius=borderRadius;
            }else{
                currSpan.innerText+=' ';
                currSpan.style.borderTop=currSpan.style.borderBottom=borderProps;
            }
        }else{
            currSpan.style.border=borderProps;
            currSpan.style.borderRadius=borderRadius;
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely not straightforward but I think it scales well enough. And if you are OK with it, it *does* modify your HTML with just one bit: adding an extra space using `innerText` so borders could join each other nicely.

Take a look at the implementation on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/mnpyqgsf/). Hope I haven't missed out any detail and really hoping this solution works for you.

Comment: This is significantly more complex than I was hoping for, but it gets the job done. I appreciate the effort you put into this.

Comment: To make it scalable, yes it is i.e. you can move your `span` elements around easily in HTML and still get the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

I have edited your code to work how you describe you want it to work, the `.boxme` tag in the class element applies the style whereby the boxme class is inside the `#box_contents` tag.

```
#boxed_contents.boxme {
  display: inline-block;

}
#boxed_contents.borderBox {
border: 2px solid #00F;
      border-radius: 5px;
}
```

:)

```
    <div id="boxed_contents">
      <span>hello</span>
      <span>world</span>
<div class='borderBox'>
      <span class='boxme'>look</span>
      <span class='boxme'>at</span>
      <span class='boxme'>me</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you know the layout of the `boxme` structure, then you can use it to force by adding an extra DIV around the chosen elements.

Comment: As I said in the original question, I do not want to edit the HTML.